# Order of an element in a group problem as follows

Tags: group-theory, ordered-groups

Let $(G,*)$ be a group, $a \in G$, and
$|a|=p$, where $p$ is a prime.

1. Prove that $|a^k|=p$ for all $1 \le k \lt p$.
2. Prove that for all $m \in \Bbb N$, either $a^m = e_G$ or $|a^m|=p$, where $e_G$ is the identity element in $G$.

**attempt:**

1. Suppose $|a^k| \ne p$ for all $1 \le k \lt p$. Then, $a^{pk} \ne e_G$. On the other hand, $|a|=p$ i.e. $a^p = e_G$. So, we have
   \begin{equation*}
   a^{pk} = (a^p)^k \ne e_G 
   \Leftrightarrow e_G^k \ne e_G
   \end{equation*}
   i.e. $e_G \ne e_G$, a contradiction.
   Hence, $|a^k| = p$.

Alternatively, by using theorem:
Let $(G,*)$ be a group, $a \in G$, and
$|a| = n$. Then, for all $t \in \Bbb N$,
\begin{equation*}
|a^t| = \frac{n}{\gcd(t,n)}
\end{equation*}
by replacing $t=k$ and $n=p$, we have:
If $p \nmid k$, then we're done.
If $p \mid k$, then $|a^k| = \frac{p}{p} = 1$, a contradiction. Hence, we must have $p \nmid k$ i.e. proved.

2. Note that for all $m \in \Bbb N$,
   \begin{equation*}
   \gcd(m,p) = 
   \begin{cases}
   p, \text{if $p \mid m$} \\
   1, \text{if $p \nmid m$}
   \end{cases}
   \end{equation*}
   Then, by theorem above, we have
   \begin{equation*}
   |a^m| = \frac{p}{\gcd(m,p)} = 
   \begin{cases}
   p, \text{if $p \mid m$} \\
   1, \text{if $p \nmid m$}
   \end{cases}
   \end{equation*}
   Thus, either $|a^m| = 1 \Rightarrow a^m = e_G$ or $|a^m| = p$, as desired.

Does the above proof true? I still have a little bit confuse in proving 1. Any elementary or a simple approach?

Comment: It may not be true that $a^{pk} \ne e_G$. $|a^k| \ne p$ could imply that there is a smaller $m < pk$ with $a^m = e_G$.

Comment: @player3236 Now, if $a^m = e_G$, then what?

Comment: Your alternate proof is valid however; you can follow the proof of that theorem instead.

Comment: @player3236 So, by that alternative proof and the included theorem, then 1 is proved. Right?

Comment: @player3236 Does it could be proved by a contradiction approach?

Comment: @player3236 What about the second statement. Does the proof valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be having some misunderstanding about the statements. In your first proof for statement 1, you tried a proof by contradiction. To do so, you need to assume that the original statement is false. What does it mean for "$|a^k| = p$ for all $1 \leq k < p$" to be false? It means **there exists** a $k$ with $1 \leq k < p$ and $|a^k| \neq p$. It **does not mean** $|a^k| \neq p$ for **all** $k$. So your first proof is not correct.

In your second proof, you made a small mistake: it is not possible that $p|k$, because $k < p$. Thus, there is no "contradiction". You simply stop before your last sentence and the proof is concluded.

Your proof for the second statement is correct.

Comment: Well, if there exists a $k$ with $1 \le k \lt p$ and $|a^k| \ne p$, then what's next? $|a^k| \ne p$ implies what?

Comment: Should I use the alternative proof for 1?

Comment: For 1: Since $k \lt p$, then $\gcd(k,p)=1$. Now, by that theorem, we have $|a^k| = \frac{p}{\gcd(k,p)} = \frac{p}{1} = p$. Like this?

Comment: @user795084 Yes, that's right.

Comment: @user795084 So perhaps here a proof by contradiction is not a good idea. The alternative proof works well. I am just pointing out why your proposed proof is not correct.

Comment: Well. Got it right now. Thanks!